# Notification about ng-option is populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am stuck in a problem, i want to get know about when select element is fully populated and ready so i can execute third party library function on that select element. the problem is i do not know when angular finishes its processing.

Here is the scenario

i have this `select` element

```
<select id="studentDropDown" ng-model="student" ng-options="stu.studentId as stu.studentName for stu in studentList" ></select>
```

and inside success of service call i assign the value

```
 $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: urlVar,
         })
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) 
          {
              $scope.studentList= data.studentList; 
              //now what to do?
          });
```

If i execute third party method just after assignment then it creates drop down with no `option` element, but if i put delay about 500ms or 1 second then it creates drop down with all values. but i want proper solution so code also works on slow machine/browsers.

Please suggest better approach,
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

i have added this code in my controller but now it populates drop down with only 1 `option` element

```
$scope.$watch('studentList', function() {
           $timeout(function() {
               console.log("i am triggering");
               $('#studentDropDown').thirdPratyFn('refresh');
           });
    });
```

**EDIT**

My bad, after implementing timeout the problem of 1 `option` element was with third party method. DOM was completed and populated at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions that come to my mind:

1. Execute the third party plugin code in the next event loop. You can use the **$timeout** service to execute your method. e.g.

   ```
   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) 
     {
         $scope.studentList= data.studentList; 
         $timeout(fnToBeExecuted,0); //make sure to inject the $timeout service in your controller
     });
   ```
2. Write a directive that will get your work done. This way you process any data bindings to be performed after your plugin executes.

Comment: My bad, after implementing timeout the problem of 1 option element was with third party method. DOM was completed and populated at that point